# Avoid force Close Error when Server is not responding

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, connection, forceclose

In my application user has to login to access the app.Login details are stored inMysql database and php files.Often app was closed due to apache server and it shows following details in my logcat,

```
[<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): <html><head>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): <title>404 Not Found</title>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): </head><body>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): <h1>Not Found</h1>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): <p>The requested URL     /bcreasearchT/Service/loginresponse.php was not found on this server.</p>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): <hr>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): <address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.medsmonit.com Port 80</address>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): </body></html>
01-17 08:59:01.935: I/tagconvertstr1(1160): ]
01-17 08:59:01.945: E/JSON Parser(1160): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-17 08:59:01.955: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-17 08:59:01.965: I/tagconvertstr3(1160): [null]
01-17 08:59:01.965: W/dalvikvm(1160): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-17 08:59:01.995: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at com.example.sms.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:280)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at com.example.sms.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-17 08:59:02.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     ... 4 more
```

How can I rectify it?Can anyone help me!

UPDATE:

This my aynctask code,

```
 class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobnum);
           passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
           uname = username.getText().toString();

              password = passw.getText().toString();    

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("VALIDATING USER...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


          proInfo.clear();

         List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

         params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
         params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pswd", password));

         JsonParser jLogin = new JsonParser();
         JSONObject json = jLogin.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params1);


         Log.i("tagconvertstr3", "["+json+"]");
         try
         {

             JSONObject jUser = json.getJSONObject(TAG_SRESL);
             userid = jUser.getString(TAG_USERID );

             successL = jUser.getString(TAG_SUCCESS1);

             proInfo.add(userid);


             }

         catch(JSONException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();

         }


        return null;
    }

   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


       if(successL.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
       {
           usrname=uname;
           new ViewProfile().execute();

       }

       else{
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
             dialog.setTitle("Login Failed");
             dialog.setCancelable(false);
             dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
             TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.errorlog);
              txt.setText("Incorrect username or password!");
              Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.release);
              dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View vd) {
                       dialog.dismiss();

            }
            });
              dialog.show();
              pDialog.dismiss();
          }
        }


    }
```

This is my json parser class,

```
  public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {


    try {

        if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            System.out.println(is);

            System.out.println("getting the content");

        }else if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("getting  all the values ");

    try {           
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);


       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();    


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    try {

        Log.i("tagconvertstr1", "["+json+"]");

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
          System.out.println("json object parse finished");

        Log.i("tagconvertstr2","["+json+"]");




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }




    return jsonObject;

}






public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();           

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+json+"]");
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+json+"]");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }


            return jsonObject;

}
```

Comment: post `LoginActivity.java` and indicate line 280

Comment: Post your AsyncTask code here... or before using the object keep one condition to check object is null or not..

Comment: what is line line 280?

Comment: @Raghunandan!!!I have pasted my code

Comment: @vishesh chandra I have pasted my code

Comment: @vimala can you indicate which is line 280 in `LoginActivity.java`?

Comment: Ctrl - L and enter line number - hope you are not counting up to 280 :)

Comment: @Raghunandan... JSONObject jUser = json.getJSONObject(TAG_SRESL);This is mt 280th line

Comment: @vimala post json parser code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject jUser = json.getJSONObject(TAG_SRESL);//This is mt 280th line
```

Your `json` is null. Start debugging. `jLogin.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params1);` is returning null.

Also move (it is better)

```
 username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobnum);
 passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

to `onCreate`

You can pass params directly to asynctask `doInbackground`

```
 new AttemptLogin().execute(username.getText().toString(),passw.getText().toString());
```

Then in doInbackground()

```
 //String... params 
 params[0] is username
 params[1]  is password
```

You are also missing

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
super.onPostExecute(file_url);
```

Comment: i.e.,have to compare the returned object to be null

Comment: @vimala nope it is just that the response form server is null. should check jsonparser code

Comment: @vimala you can use `if(TextUtils.isEmpty("yourstring"))` this  Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

Comment: Your Idea is worked for me..but it often stuck some where and show wrong output

Comment: @vimala check your response from the server

Comment: first time it receive response as null after that it alwalys receive response as No...even net is available and also for valid details

Comment: @vimala post the code where you make the http request to get the response. The JsonParser code

Comment: @Raghunandan..I have posted my json parser class

Comment: @Raghunandan..I got this"error converting result java.io.IOException:attempted read on closed stream"

Comment: @vimala `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();`Then `String json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)`. try this

Comment: !Where I have to put this code..Java parser is separate class file...From there how can I use json string u declared here

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check the response code from the server and act based on that because it seams that the json creation fails and maybe that causes the nullpointer.

Comment: i tried that by comparing null with response..but it does not work

Comment: @vimala the response code is int so that can not be equal to null. Check for the int value and act based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Kepp condition before using json object. Replace your code in doInBackground.

```
try {
    if(json != null){
        JSONObject jUser = json.getJSONObject(TAG_SRESL);
        userid = jUser.getString(TAG_USERID );
        successL = jUser.getString(TAG_SUCCESS1);
        proInfo.add(userid);
    }
}catch(JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Check here string before checking the equalsIgnoreCase, Replace your onPostExecute code.

```
if(successL != null && successL.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
    usrname=uname;
    new ViewProfile().execute();
}
```

Please try it.

Comment: checking is fine but the real problem is the json returned is null and that should be fixed first

Comment: @vishesh chandra..Thanks it works but in my post execute i cant able to configure properly...

Comment: successL is string how u can compare it with !=??/

Comment: @vimala you must go with Raghunandan instruction, He is right.

Comment: @vishesh chandra Your Idea is worked for me..but it often stuck some where and show wrong output